# mysql error log

Tags: mysql

I removed the error log file from the data directory. I have not specified any path for the error log in my.cnf file. There seems to be no error log file available. Where does mysql now writing the log?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Hmm. It could be that it creates the error log file only when an error occurs. Is that possible?

Comment: CentOS is my operating system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It do not write to any error log file if you haven't setup in my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu/Debian then it could be in /var/log or perhaps the syslog. Why don't you specify where you want the log to go in your configuration file and then you will be able to find it easily.

You might be able to use `find mysql.log` in the root dir in the mean time.

As Pekka says it won't write the log unless there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Should be in the same directory again. I don't see any reason, why it sould create the logfile in a different directory, if it does not exist.

So, why is it not created?

- Maybe file permissions don't allow the creation
- Or as Pekka suggested, there haven't been any errors since.

Try creating an empty error_log file in this directory and make sure, it has permissions, so the user, mysql is running under, can write into it.